# find Argument list too long

Tags: linux, find, xargs

I want to search in many many files for a string.

I used `find /archive/* -print0 | xargs -0 grep 'robert' -sl`

Is there a simple method to do it ?

Answer (score 5):

The shell expands `*`. Just omit it, and `find` will figure out what to do.

```
find /archive -print0 | xargs -0 grep 'robert' -sl
```

Comment: wooow :D:D thx it works

Comment: +1 have a read up on how "globs" work. It's really useful to know.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for `find`. Just use.

```
grep -m 1 -rsl 'robert' archive/
```

Comment: ok, is there any way say, if zou found 100 files its ok and print them out and stop searching more ?

Comment: @Roby `grep -rsl 'robert' archive/ | head -100`

Comment: @Timofey: is grep then stopping ? because i had really large files.... like 2mio.

Comment: @Roby Yes of course.

Comment: @Roby: `grep -rslm 100 'robert' archive/`